# Html5 Canvas rotate single element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I know that there are many similiar questions already asked on stackoverflow, but still, I can not figure out how to do it. I want to rotate only ball texture. draw is called with timer:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var width;
var height;
var ready;
var textures;
var loadIndex;
var loadCount;
var keyCodes;
var mouseLoc;

var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerVelocity;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    width = canvas.width;
    height = canvas.height;
    textures = [];
    loadingCount = 0;
    keyCodes = [];
    mouseLoc = {};

    playerX = 0;
    playerY = 0;
    playerVelocity = 6;

    textures['Background'] = loadTexture('./textures/Background.png');
    textures['Ball'] = loadTexture('./textures/Ball.png');

    setInterval(function(){ 
        if(loadingCount == 0) {
            update();
            draw();
        }
    }, 50);
}

function update(){
    if(keyCodes[37])
        playerX -= playerVelocity;
    if(keyCodes[38])
        playerY -= playerVelocity;
    if(keyCodes[39])
        playerX += playerVelocity;
    if(keyCodes[40])
        playerY += playerVelocity;
}

function draw() {
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //ctx.beginPath();
    drawBackground();
    drawPlayer();
    //ctx.closePath();
    //ctx.fill();
}

function drawBackground(){
    ctx.drawImage(textures['Background'], 0, 0, width, height);
}

function drawPlayer(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(0.17);
    ctx.drawImage(textures['Ball'], playerX, playerY, 100, 100);
    ctx.restore();
}

function loadTexture(src){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    loadingCount++;
    image.onload = function(){
        loadingCount--;
    };
    return image;
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt){
    keyCodes[evt.keyCode] = true;
    evt.returnValue = false;
}
document.onkeyup = function(evt){
    keyCodes[evt.keyCode] = false;
}

document.onmousemove = function(evt){
    mouseLoc.x = evt.layerX;
    mouseLoc.y = evt.layerY;
}
document.onmousedown = function(evt){
    mouseLoc.down = true;
}
document.onmouseup = function(evt){
    mouseLoc.down = false;
}

init();
```

Comment: did you want the ball to rotate by an _additional_ 0.17 radians for _each_ frame drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to give the illusion of the ball *continuing* to rotate, you should increase the rotation angle for each frame drawn.

As written, your code will give the ball a *fixed* rotation of 0.17 radians on each frame.

```
var frame = 0;

function drawPlayer() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(0.17 * frame);
    ...
    ctx.restore();
}

function draw() {
    ++frame;
    drawPlayer();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @karaxuna I presumed that you realised this after I added my comment to your question.

Comment: No but it does not matter any more, because your answer will help others who have this kind of trouble

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save and restore the state of the canvas('s state-machine)

```
function drawPlayer(){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(0.17);
    ctx.drawImage(textures['Ball'], playerX, playerY, 100, 100);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Try adding a ctx.translate(playerX, playerY) before ctx.rotate. I wish we knew what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks, i was missing one thing: rotate angle is allways 0.17, I'm not increasing it

Answer (score 1):

You want to use delta time for calculating the distance of your rotation. That is, the time that has passed since the last frame. That will make your rotation smoother should your browser hiccup and lose a frame here or there.

So store the time of each frame so you can make the comparison between frames and set your rotation speed as radians per second.